# what does condition if(k & 1) mean in c?

Tags: c

Here's an example of code in c, i'm not sure what does condition "k & 1" means.

```
int k,i,c;
k = i >> c;
if (k & 1)
   printf("1");
else
   printf("0");
```

Comment: Please, learn to initialize the local variables. before using them. Actually initializing any variable, to some value, is always a good idea, IMHO. if say, `k` is `5`, in `4-bits(nibble)` this will become `0101`. Now performing `AND` operation of this binary number with `1`, like `0101 & 0001` will give, `0001` as a result, since the last bit of `k` is `ON` or k is `odd`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`k & 1` does a bitwise AND operation of the `k` variable and the `1` literal.  The expression results in either `0` (if the LSB of `k` is `0`) or `1` (if the LSB of `k` is `1`).  As the expression is the condition for the `if` statement, it is implicitly cast to `bool`, for which `1` maps to `true` and `0` maps to `false`.